# Unable to Copy Audio Channels with Discreet Audio Channel Positions?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get a small segment of a ProRes QT clip with multiple PCM (WAV) audio channels which I want to copy to the output video however; whenever I try to copy the audio tracks to the output with the map parameter it uses audio track 1 for every single output audio stream instead of mapping ch 1 -> ch 1, ch 2 -> ch 2, etc.. In the Media Info there is a value called "discreet-0" in the channel position field which may be causing problems. For example:

```
Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : in24
Duration                                 : 2 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 152 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Discrete-0
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 17.9 MiB (1%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-06-19 23:57:56
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-06-19 23:57:56
```

My command looks like this:

```
C:\ffmpeg-20160913\bin\ffmpeg -i "C:\TEST\input.mov" -map 0:0 -vcodec prores -profile:v 2 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:05 -map 0:1 -acodec copy -map 0:2 -acodec copy -map 0:3 -acodec copy -map 0:4 -acodec copy -map 0:5 -acodec copy -map 0:6 -acodec copy -map 0:7 -acodec copy -map 0:8 -acodec copy -map 0:9 -acodec copy -map 0:10 -acodec copy -map 0:11 -acodec copy "test.prores.mov" -loglevel verbose
```

My ffmpeg output:

```
C:\ffmpeg-20160913\bin>C:\ffmpeg-20160913\bin\ffmpeg -i "C:\TEST\input.mov" -map 0:0 -vcodec prores -profile:v 2 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:05 -map 0:1 -acodec copy -map 0:2 -acodec copy -ma
p 0:3 -acodec copy -map 0:4 -acodec copy -map 0:5 -acodec copy -map 0:6 -acodec copy -map 0:7 -acodec copy -map 0:8 -acodec copy -map 0:9 -acodec copy -map 0:10 -acodec copy -map 0:11 -
acodec copy "test.prores.mov" -loglevel verbose
ffmpeg version N-81646-gc19da0c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconf
ig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libi
lbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 55.101 / 57. 55.101
  libavformat    57. 48.103 / 57. 48.103
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 62.100 /  6. 62.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.5 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.6 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.7 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.8 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.9 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.10 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.11 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.12 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\TEST\input.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:10.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 153843 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores, 1 reference frame (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080, 139955 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default
)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:8(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:9(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:10(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:11(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:12(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:13(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
File 'test.prores.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000004f8b00] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv422p10le tb:1/24000 fr:24000/1001 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
[mov @ 000000000046f000] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 11 times
Output #0, mov, to 'test.prores.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf57.48.103
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores, 1 reference frame (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.04 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavc57.55.101 prores
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:8(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:9(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:10(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:11(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-06-19T23:57:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> prores (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:5 (copy)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:6 (copy)
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:7 (copy)
  Stream #0:8 -> #0:8 (copy)
  Stream #0:9 -> #0:9 (copy)
  Stream #0:10 -> #0:10 (copy)
  Stream #0:11 -> #0:11 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
No more output streams to write to, finishing.e=00:00:05.01 bitrate=187170.8kbits/s speed=0.874x
frame=  120 fps= 21 q=-0.0 Lsize=  122642kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=200336.3kbits/s speed=0.869x
video:114881kB audio:7742kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.015734%
Input file #0 (C:\TEST\input.mov):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 383 packets read (243519202 bytes); 383 frames decoded;
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:2 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:3 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:4 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:5 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:6 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:7 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:8 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:9 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:10 (audio): 752 packets read (2306304 bytes);
  Input stream #0:11 (audio): 706 packets read (2165232 bytes);
  Input stream #0:12 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes);
  Input stream #0:13 (data): 0 packets read (0 bytes);
  Total: 8609 packets (268747474 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (test.prores.mov):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 120 frames encoded; 120 packets muxed (117638160 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:2 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:3 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:4 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:5 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:6 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:7 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:8 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:9 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:10 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Output stream #0:11 (audio): 235 packets muxed (720720 bytes);
  Total: 2705 packets (125566080 bytes) muxed
```

Any idea on what's causing this?

Comment: It appears that the correct streams are being mapped, but perhaps I don't quite understand what issue you are experiencing. Also, why are you re-encoding the video? Just to change the profile? Note that you can just do `ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c copy -c:v prores -ss 10 -t 5 output`.

Comment: Yes, it appears to have copied as expected. Note, you do not need to specify `-acodec copy` after each map. Once will do.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the metadata and remove the "Channel positions" information from each stream?